# Dart's extension method

Tags: flutter, dart

There is a Person class, and an extension of the Person class, as follows:

```
class Person {
  bool get isEmpty{
    return this == null;
  }
}

extension PersonExt on Person {
  bool get isEmptyByExt {
    return this == null;
  }
}
```

The call is as follows：

```
Person person;
var result = person.isEmptyByExt;
print(result);
var result2 = person.isEmpty; // ERROR
print(result2);
```

`person.isEmptyByExt;` There is no problem with the call;

but `person.isEmpty;` will report an error here:

```
NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'isEmpty' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: isEmpty
```

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling an instance method involves virtual dispatch and requires an actual object instance for inheritance and method overrides to work at runtime.  It never makes sense for `this` to be `null` in an instance method.

Extension methods are syntactic sugar for static functions to make them look like instance methods.  That is:

> ```dart
> extension PersonExt on Person {
>   bool get isEmptyByExt {
>     return this == null;
>   }
> }
> ```

is essentially equivalent to:

```dart
class PersonExt {
  static bool isEmptyByExt(Person _this) {
    return _this == null;
  }
}
```

They work on the static (known at compile-time) type of the object and not the object's actual runtime type. (This is why extension methods can't work on `dynamic` types, and they cannot be overridden by derived classes.) Since they're the equivalent of a `static` function, the object could be `null`.

Note that this is a bit clearer with null-safety enabled, where there is a distinction between:

- `extension PersonExt on Person` (`this` cannot be `null`)
- `extension PersonExt on Person?` (`this` *can* be `null`).

Further reading: [Dart Extension Methods Fundamentals](https://medium.com/dartlang/extension-methods-2d466cd8b308)