# Is it possible to create Dart class extensions that implement or override inherited methods?

Tags: dart, extension-methods

I'd like to use code generators that create extensions for classes that should implement some boilerplate methods, but apparently I cannot :)

Sample code:

```
abstract class Base {
   foo(int param) { print("Base::foo $param"); }
}

class Derived extends Base {
  
}

extension DerivedWithFoo on Derived {
  foo(int param) { print("Derived::foo $param");}
}

void main() {
 final d = Derived();
 d.foo(5); 
}
```

Output:

`Base::foo 5`

It looks like that extension method calls are somehow early bound?

Thanks.

Comment: Extension methods are syntactic sugar for static functions.  They depend entirely on the static type of the object, so they cannot be polymorphic.  See https://dart.dev/guides/language/extension-methods#static-types-and-dynamic

Comment: And also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/68910900/.

Comment: Thanks, for some reason I could not find this (quickly) in the Dart manuals.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this with an `extension`.

You can try using a `mixin` instead, like so:

```dart
abstract class Base {
  foo(int param) { print("Base::foo $param"); }
}

mixin MyMixin {
  foo(int param) { print("Mixin::foo $param");}
}

class Derived extends Base with MyMixin {
}

void main() {
  final d = Derived();
  d.foo(5);
}
```

Output:
`Mixin::foo 5`