# Operator overloading within an extension in dart / Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, overloading, operator-keyword

I wanted to be able to compare two DateTimes in dart with simple operators so I created a file called 'date_comparison.dart' containing the following code:

```dart
extension DateComparison on DateTime {
  bool operator >(other) => compareTo(other) > 0;
  bool operator <(other) => compareTo(other) < 0;
  bool operator >=(other) => compareTo(other) >= 0;
  bool operator <=(other) => compareTo(other) <= 0;
}
```

In another file I import this file and use the comparison operators and VS Code doesn't give me any errors. *(The code of that file is a bit too much to post it here but the point is that everything works apart from that)*

However, when I try to run the app I get a runtime error `NoSuchMethodError` saying that »Class 'DateTime' has no instance method '<='.«

Comment: I have pasted your code in a project and had no problem. Have you tried to clean your project and launch it again?

Comment: I have but that did not fix the problem.

Comment: DateTime has `isBefore` and `isAfter` methods: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/DateTime-class.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I fixed the problem:

Turns out that whenever a variable of which the type is modified by an extension is of type dynamic, even when a correct value is assigned to that variable, the extension gets ignored.

For my part, I accidentally forgot to declare the DateTime type on a variable on which I wanted to use my operator extension so it was dynamic and the extension had no effect.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/68910900/ for why extensions don't work on `dynamic` types.  You can catch cases where you accidentally use `dynamic` types by [settiing `implicit-dynamic: false`](https://dart.dev/guides/language/analysis-options#enabling-additional-type-checks) in your analysis options.